# How to reverse engineer data from a program sending data to some domain using XML-RPC?

Tags: php, methods, xml-rpc

Imagine there is a program which is sending some data to one address call it domain.com to this address it sends some data about food - its qualities and other stuff. How can I reverse engineer these data with the help of the xml-rpc which it is based on?

I need to create some function of catching methots to get hash, login, Seller, listAdvertisement, addAdvertisement, delAdvertisement, Photo etc. I heard there should be some opensource libraries but I did not have any luck finding them or manual how to do this properly in PHP script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly recommend using **WireShark** (https://www.wireshark.org) for taking a trace of network traffic between the program and the web server it is connected to. I use it all the time to monitor traffic in our servers during development; and even in production servers.

It's very handy to look into packets exchanged and supports so many protocols across all layers; not only XML-RPC. It also supports multiple file format for traces taken by other programs. I primarily use it with tcpdump in Linux servers and snoop with Solaris. So, you can take a trace in server and look at the traffic later on using WireShark.

Once you take a trace of traffic, you can look at the XML-RPC payload and get all information needed reverse-engineer the protocol (e.g. operations, parameters and values, expected responses...etc)

I hope this answer helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sniffing proxy, eg [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/). It will log all trafic going through.